# Distribution of subvector of vector uniform on a sphere

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, spherical-coordinates

For a random vector $\mathbf{X} = [x_1,x_2,...,x_n] \in \mathbb{R}^n$ uniformly distributed on the surface of the unit sphere, the PDF is the inverse of the surface
$$f_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x}) = 2\pi^{-n/2}\Gamma(n/2) \delta(\left\lVert \mathbf{x}\right\rVert = 1) \tag{1}$$
where $\delta$ is the delta function.

I am interested in 
$$f_{X_1,...,X_{n-1}}(x_1,...,x_{n-1}) = \int_{-1}^1 f_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x}) dx_n \\= 2\pi^{-n/2}\Gamma(n/2) \int_{-1}^1 \delta(x_n^2 = 1 - x_1^2-...-x_{n-1}^2) dx_n = 2\pi^{-n/2}\Gamma(n/2) \times 2$$
because there is 2 points $x_n^2 = \pm\sqrt{1 - x_1^2-...-x_{n-1}^2}$.

I am not sure this is correct because if I continue like that, the marginal distribution $f_{X_1}(x_1)$ will be something does not depend on $x_1$ which is not true.

Thanks for hints.

Comment: $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots + x_n^2 = 1$ surface area is $\frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$, right? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html

Answer (score 1):

[1] V. I. Khokhlov, "The Uniform Distribution on a Sphere in ${\bf R}^S$. Properties of Projections. I.",
Theory Probab. Appl., 50(3), 386–399, 2006.

Let $n\ge 3$ be an integer. Let $(X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n)$ be a random vector with a uniform distribution on the unit sphere
$S_n = \{(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 = 1\}$.

Then, $X_1$ has the probability density
$$p_{X_1}(x_1) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})}(1-x_1^2)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}, \
\ - 1 < x_1 < 1.$$
If $n=3$, it is $f_{X_1}(x_1) = \frac{1}{2}, \ -1 < x_1 < 1$ which is a uniform distribution.

$(X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_k)$ ($k \le n-2$) has the joint probability density 
\begin{align}
f_{X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_k}(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_k)
&= \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{\pi^{k/2}\Gamma(\frac{n-k}{2})}
(1 - x_1^2 - x_2^2 - \cdots - x_k^2)^{\frac{n-k-2}{2}}, \\
&\quad (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k)\in \mathbb{R}^k, \ 0 < x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_k^2 < 1.
\end{align}

Comment: Do you know how one can see that $p_{X_{1}}$ has that distribution function?Is there a cdf to differentiate?

Comment: @user135520 Do you mean if $F_{X_1}(x_1)$ admits a closed form for general $n$? I am not sure. Perhaps we need special functions.

Comment: I think I actually found an overflow post that answers the question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359643/marginal-density-of-uniform-spherical-distribution

Comment: I heard informally from a professor that $F_{X_{1}}$ is related to the uniform distribution on the $n$-ball. I wanted to follow this.

Comment: @user135520 Thank you for the link in MO.

Comment: No problem, the Heavyside function that get's mentioned in one of the answers, was likely what I was thinking of.

Comment: @user135520 I think you mean Carlo Beenakker's answer.

Answer (score 0):

One can think about this problem very geometrically: Let $F(r)$ be defined as the surface area of the boundary of a $n$ dimensional ball of radius $r$. Then the pdf of $X_1$ is $f_1(x)= \frac{F(r)}{\int_{-1}^{1} F(r) dx}$ where $r=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: Thanks, however I want to calculate $f_{X_1,...,X_{n-1}}(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$ not $f_{X_1}(x_1)$.